# UseParams doesn't get the id from the url but it gets the "edit" instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is the details component of a class:

```
export default observer(function ClassDetails() {
const { classesStore } = useStore();
const { loadClass, selectedClass: classR, loadingInitial } = classesStore;
const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();

useEffect(() => {
    if (id) loadClass(id)
}, [id, loadClass]);

if (loadingInitial || !classR) return <LoadingComponent content="Loading Class"/>;

return (
    <Card fluid>
        <Image src={`/assets/categoryImages/culture.jpg`} />
        <Card.Content>
            <Card.Header>{classR.id}</Card.Header>
            <Card.Description>
                <div>{classR.id}</div>
                <div>{classR.className}</div>
            </Card.Description>
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Content extra>
            <Button.Group widths='2'>
                <Button as={Link} to={`/classes/edit/${classR.id}`} basic color="blue" content='Edit' />
            </Button.Group>
        </Card.Content>
    </Card>
)})
```

Everything works fine when I open e certain class, the useParams get the Id from the url stores it and send it to the function loadClass with the certain id. But when I press the edit button, instead of storing the id part of the url, it stores the "edit" part of the url and then sends it to the loadClass function which returns no result of course. Why isn't it getting the id but it get the "edit" from url.

These are my routes:

```
<Route path='/classes/:id' component={ClassDetails} />
<Route key={location.key} path={['/createClass', `/classes/edit/:id`]} component={ClassForm} />
```

The first one it gets the id correctly, but for the second one it doesnt

Now if I change the routes of edit button to {`/edit/${classR.id}`} and the path to `/edit/:id` it works.

Why is that?
Thank you